# Flutter app: upgrading to new code base of an app

Tags: android, flutter

We have an app with new code base, We want to seamlessly upgrade users with v1 to v2, when I try to upgrade to v2 with same package, I get Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Existing package com.mypackage.name signatures do not match newer version; ignoring!]

What should i do to seamlessly upgrade users?

I have kept same signing files, but still i am getting this error

Comment: To upload app of new project, you need to have same package name as older project otherwise it won't work.

Comment: i have the same package name,

Answer (score 1):

You should manually verify which signature the v1 APK hasand compare it with the new one.

Keep in mind that if you downloaded v2 from the Play Store, chances are that the app was resigned by google with a key that you don't own if app signing is enabled.